# Naming global variables in a structured way

Tags: vba, excel

My current project has global constants that define certain rows and columns in workbooks that this project will be searching through. I have defined them as such:

```
Public Const headRow As Integer = 1
Public Const descRow As Integer = 2
Public Const pnumCol As Integer = 1
Public Const teamCol As Integer = 2
Public Const dateCol As Integer = 3
Public Const hourCol As Integer = 4
Public Const typeCol As Integer = 5
Public Const taskCol As Integer = 6
Public Const noteCol As Integer = 7
```

I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to define these that would allow me to write these in a way such as:

```
ColumnNums.team
ColumnNums.task
ColumnNums.note     'etc
```

I think something similar to this could be done by defining my own type, but that would probably not be worthwhile. I'm basically wanting this to be an easy way to remember the variable names as I write more code, as well as to be able to count how many items I have in each group. Would a Type or Collection be useful in this case?

Comment: Yeah just put it in a class module and have properties instead of constants

Comment: Maybe this question is better suited and hosted at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: nah it's ok for stack to be honest, see my answer below.

Comment: while it is not part of the question, if there is no real necessary for a value to be integer, it should be declared as [Long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long)

Comment: Good point @DirkReichel and a fab question there in ur link. looks like I learnt something new today too :-) going to update my answer to use a long now lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For mixed variable types, you can put it in a class module, name the class module `ColumnNumbers` and put the following code in:

```
Public Property Get Team() As Long
    Team = 1
End Property

Public Property Get TeamName() As String
    TeamName = "Team One! :-)"
End Property
```

Then you can use it in any module like this:

```
Dim colNums As New ColumnNumbers

Sub foo()
MsgBox colNums.Team
End Sub
```

If you only want to return `long` values, put it in an enum:

```
Enum ColumnNumbers
    Team = 1
    Description = 2
End Enum

Sub foo()
MsgBox ColumnNumbers.Team
End Sub
```

Chip pearson has already done a fantastic job of describing enums [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Enums.aspx) it's worth a read if you have yet to discover them.

Comment: Did not know about `enum`. Learned something new^^ @JohnColeman

Comment: Don't ignore the class module option, it will get you started on object oriented programming and it's a much better way to think. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use public arrays like this:

```
Public ColumnNum(0 To 2) As Long
Public RowNum(0 To 2) As Long
```

Used together with an enum:

```
Public Enum Category
    team
    task
    note 'etc.
End Enum
```

Then things like `ColumnNum(team)` will function like a public variable:

```
Sub test1()
    ColumnNum(team) = 5
End Sub

Sub test2()
    Debug.Print ColumnNum(team)
End Sub
```

If these two subs are run in order than `5` is printed.